# NextJS Node Modules are large in size due to `swc` files

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, cloud-foundry

I'm running into an issue with NextJS node modules. In a work comp, I used `create-next-app` with TS. After installation, I noticed the node_module folder size is about 1.4GB; extremely high. Its got some `swc` folders such linux, android.

This is causing an issue when deploying the next app due to that large size in the node_modules; I'm using cloud foundry for deployment.

```
Node version on that work comp is v16.14.2

NPM version is 8.5.0
```

In a personal computer, i did the exact same thing for creating an app, but the node_module size is about 255M. I noticed it doesn't have all that extra swc folders.

```
Node version on the personal comp is v18

NPM version is 8.5.0
```

I changed the node version in my personal comp to v16 and see if it has the same results, but the node_modules has a small size, about 255M.

So I'm perplexed why the node_modules in the work comp has a large size, and it has those extra `swc` files. I understand that you need the `swc` files for performance, but I can't comprehend why it's so large in the work comp.

In the personal comp, it only has one `swc` file which is ok, and the app performs ok.

Has anyone run into this kind of scenario? Your help will appreciated; I'm new to nextjs and its deployment process.

Comment: Did you find the reason of this problem @medev21 ?

Comment: @FR073N i haven't found the reason, it's still a mistery